# How to change color in elevatedbutton when it pressed in flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I'm building a VPN application with flutter. After I click connect, the color of the button already change from blue to red. But when I click disconnect, the color of the button didn't turn back to blue.

This is my code:

```
bool isPressed = true;

ElevatedButton(
   onPressed: () async {
      if (state == FlutterVpnState.disconnected) {
         FlutterVpn.connectIkev2EAP(
            server: _addressController.text,
            username: _usernameController.text,
            password: _passwordController.text,
         );
         setState(() {
            isPressed = !isPressed;
         },
         );
      }
      if (state == FlutterVpnState.connected) {
         FlutterVpn.disconnect();
      }
      if (state == FlutterVpnState.error) {
         FlutterVpn.disconnect();
      }
   },
   child: Text(
      state == FlutterVpnState.disconnected? 'Connect' : 'Disconnect',
   ),
   style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
      primary: isPressed ? Colors.blue : Colors.redAccent
   ),
),
```

My question is how to turn back the color to blue?
Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: that means you need to change colour when it is disconnected right..? 
in connected state it's working but when user click in disconnect then it will not be change. 

Right..?

Answer (score 1):

You need to set a bool for offline and online, then just changed the color based on that bool using theme.

```
bool isPressed = true;
```

```
ElevatedButton(
      onPressed: () async {
       if (state == FlutterVpnState.disconnected) {
         FlutterVpn.connectIkev2EAP(
            server: _addressController.text,
            username: _usernameController.text,
            password: _passwordController.text,
         );
         setState(() {
            isPressed = true;
         },
         );
      }
      if (state == FlutterVpnState.connected) {
         FlutterVpn.disconnect();

         setState(() {
            isPressed = false;
         },
      }
      if (state == FlutterVpnState.error) {
         FlutterVpn.disconnect();

         setState(() {
            isPressed = false;
         },
      }
   },
   child: Text(
      state == FlutterVpnState.disconnected? 'Connect' : 'Disconnect',
   ),
   style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
      primary: isPressed ? Colors.blue : Colors.redAccent
   ),
),
```

Comment: I've tried your solution, but it's almost right. I've try to change isConnected = true to isConnected = false in onPressed function and vice versa, then I've got what I want. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `MaterialStateProperty`:

```
                ElevatedButton(
                  style: ButtonStyle(
                    backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith<Color>(
                      (Set<MaterialState> states) {
                        if (states.contains(MaterialState.pressed)) {
                          return Colors.green;
                        }

                        return Colors.red;
                      },
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
```

Answer (score 0):

try with this code.

```
bool isConnected = false;
ElevatedButton(
onPressed: () async {
  if (state == FlutterVpnState.disconnected) {
     FlutterVpn.connectIkev2EAP(
        server: _addressController.text,
        username: _usernameController.text,
        password: _passwordController.text,
     );
        isConnected = true;      
  }
  if (state == FlutterVpnState.connected) {
     FlutterVpn.disconnect();
     isConnected = false;
  }
  if (state == FlutterVpnState.error) {
     FlutterVpn.disconnect();
     isConnected = false;
  }
 
   setState(() {});
},
child: Text(
  state == FlutterVpnState.disconnected? 'Connect' : 'Disconnect',
),
style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
  backgroundColor: isPressed ? Colors.blue : Colors.redAccent
 ),
),
```